# Install PHP with the apk on Android

Tags: php, android

Is it possible to install and run PHP code on Android from an APK and how?

I have an Android APP that connects to a server and exchanges various information.
The server is built on Apache, PHP and MySQL.

All working well so far, but I now need to port the PHP operation on the Android APP to cut all need for the server as that limits the APP working offline.

I need to make the Android APK install PHP along and execute PHP code directly just like I would do it on a Linux machine in the command-line.

Comment: I did not ask how to build PHP apps. I asked how to install PHP along with the apk.

Comment: I do think this question is different than the one marked as a duplicate. It may be a little subtle, but they are asking slightly different things, and the answers to that question don't answer this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While there is a semi complete [PHP for Android](http://phpforandroid.net/) port, I'd recommend rewriting your PHP functionality in native Android Java, as it will give you much better compatibility and reach on devices.

Comment: The PHP code is so big and complicated using Einstein level of mathematical calculations that it would take a very long time to do it.

Comment: @tntu If its that complex, you should genuinely spend time porting it to Java as running complex operations in a semi stable ported version of PHP on a mobile device isn't going to be great performance wise.

Comment: At one point you have marked this question as duplicate and at another point, you have posted answer with the same link. How strange !!

Comment: @PareshMayani There is nothing 'wrong' with both voting to close and answering a question. While it is not a standard thing to do  - I wouldn't - many do it.

Comment: @AndrewBarber How strange !! Same thing is suggested in existed answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/3226893/379693, sorry Raghav.